# C++ template specialization for specific values

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have struct `Opers` with some arithmetic operations: `mult()`, `div()`, `mod()`.

And I need to specialize template for certain values of `n`. Here is example for `Opers<1>`.

But, also I want to do specialization for `n` that are powers of 2 ( n = 2,4,8,16, ...) – in this case I can optimize operations `mult()`  and `div()` (using bitwise shift left or right).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<int n> struct Opers {
    int mult(int x){
        return n*x;
    }
    int div(int x){
        return x / n;
    }   
    int mod(int x){
        return x % n;
    }   
};
template<> struct Opers<1> {
    int mult(int x){
        return 1;
    }
    int div(int x){
        return x;
    }   
    int mod(int x){
        return 0;
    }           
};
int main() {
    Opers<1> el2;
    cout << el2.mult(3) <<endl;
}
```

I'm looking for construction like

```
template<> struct Opers<isPowerOfTwo()>
    int mult(int x){
        // do smth
     }
```

Is it possible or what manual should I read?

**UPD.** Using C++11 is allowed, and even would be better.

Comment: Ahh... optimize by using shifts. The compiler will be like, "whoa, I would *never* have thought of that"...

Comment: I know that it doesn't matter for compiler! It's just an example (connected with my study task), and I can't find right construction or approach to code that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, you could do it this way. First of all, change your primary template so that it accepts a second, dummy parameter:

```
template<int n, typename = void>
struct Opers 
{
    // ...
};
```

Then, write a `constexpr` function that determines whether an integer is a power of 2:

```
constexpr bool is_power_of_two(int x)
{
    return (x == 1) || ((x % 2 == 0) && is_power_of_two(x / 2));
}
```

Finally, use SFINAE to enable or disable the specialization based on the result of your `constexpr` function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int n>
struct Opers<n, typename std::enable_if<is_power_of_two(n)>::type>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Will not `x & (x - 1) == 0` check the same thing?

Comment: @soon: Perhaps, yes, but I find my version easier to understand. Moreover, this is done at compile-time, so performance is unlikely to be an issue

Comment: What about `template<int n, bool ispow2 = is_power_of_two(n)>`?

Comment: @DyP: That's also a possibility, but I think my solution is more general, because it allows adding new specializations without changing the primary template

Answer (score 3):

```
template <int N, typename = void>
struct Operations
{
    // ....
};

template <int N, typename = std::enable_if<(N & (N - 1))>::type>
struct Operations
{
    // ....
};
```